# Classify the nature of a quadrilateral determined by the coordinate axes and lines $y=\frac{3}{5}x+\frac{4}{5}$ and $y=\frac{-5}{3}x+\frac{16}{3}$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, quadrilateral

I have a problem in determining the nature of a quadrilateral. This is generated by the intersection of two straight lines:
$$y=\frac{3}{5}x+\frac{4}{5}\qquad y=\frac{-5}{3}x+\frac{16}{3}$$
Here the quadrilateral [image] I can't classify it as a particular quadrilateral but I have verified that $DC=CB$...this could be a trapezoid?

Comment: FWIW it's a cyclic quadrilateral, but it's not a trapezium

Comment: It’s a cyclic quadrilateral because $\angle DCB = \angle DAB = 90^\circ, \implies \angle DCB + \angle DAB= 180^\circ.$

Comment: Ok thank you! Do you think can be circoscribed or inscribed?

Comment: cyclic=inscribed in a circle.